# Getting an Error while trying to get email message body in last mail, Nodejs GMAIL api

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

Hope you all safe,
My scenario is -> Get the message list and get the ID for each message. Get the message body based on the message ID. Finally, the text is Base64 converted,

```
const gmailGetMessagesAsync = promisify(gmail.users.messages.get);
const gmailListMessagesAsync = promisify(gmail.users.messages.list);

let res = await gmailListMessagesAsync({
        auth: oauth2Client,
        userId: 'me'
    });
    const newestMessageId = res.messages[0].id;

res = await gmailGetMessagesAsync({
        auth: oauth2Client,
        userId: 'me',
        id: newestMessageId
    });

 const base64mailBody = res.payload.parts[0].body.data;
const mailBody = new Buffer(base64mailBody, 'base64').toString();
```

With this I am getting an error,

```
(node:9041) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at main (/NODEGMAIL/getLabels.js:42:37)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:9041) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

Appreciate your help on this matter

Comment: Can you do a `.catch()` ? the `rest` object does not contain the `message` property

Comment: @ Aviv Lo - more explanation please, I am new to this NODE.js that's why .

Comment: Ok.` Do a console.log(res)` Let's look at how `res` looks like?

Comment: console.log(res); --> output [object Object]

Comment: `console.log(JSON.parse(res));` How about this?

Comment: I change it , console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); with "parse" getting error, So with this , got json object, cannot pu there becaz its too long

Comment: @Aviv Lo , Understood, got the result , Thanks, sorry for the bothering you

Comment: No worries. So is the problem solved?

Comment: yes , done Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

`JSON.parse(res)` and you will get your object. You can access the content and manipulate it afterward.